# How to make CMake use specified compiler?

Tags: cmake, clang, fedora

I'm currently using Fedora 30.
First I've already set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++` and `CMake` output says it's using clang. However when I use make to actually build the project gcc is selected instead of clang.

In previous versions this problem can be solved by setting `CCACHE_CC=clang++` but it's not working now.Can anyone help please?

Comment: Are you building in your source directory?

Answer (score 2):

OK. I figured out that it was nvcc that it uses gcc by default. nvcc default compiler can be changed by the following command.

```
nvcc --compiler-bindir /usr/bin/clang++
```

Answer (score 0):

Force clearing the cmake cache to regenerate the build system.

```
make rebuild_cache
```

Comment: Actually I've done this multiple times. I think this issue is caused by things outside the configuration system.